# Is it possible to create a task using the box-api v2 in a folder?

Tags: box-api

I have successfully created tasks using the box-api v2 on files. However, I often need to create a task in a folder, e.g. for someone to upload a file to the folder, not simply review a file in that folder.

It doesn't appear to be possible now, is that true? if so, any plans to make that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to assign a task to a folder via the API or the Box web application. I don't believe Box has any current plans to add tasks either via the web or programmatically.

Rory